# Como ver Query en Django sin el <QuerySet [<X: Y>]>

Tags: python, sql, django

Como estan comunidad? creo q es muy simple la pregunta pero me estoy volviendo loco, yo se que lo vi en algun lado vi que esto se puede hacer pero no logro ubicar en donde. Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Django y necesito hacer una consulta en una funcion de Python en el views.py para obtener el valor de una tabla el problema es que cuando hago la consulta me devuelve toda la query, es decir:

```
view = Alumnos.objects.filter(id="3") 
print(view)
<QuerySet [<Alumnos: Martin>]>
```

Ahora yo solo necesito que que la respuesta sea simplemente **Martin** sin todo el agregado que realiza la respuesta, es esto posible?

Podria limpiarlo de alguna manera con diferentes metodos pero entiendo que hay una manera mas facil mediante algun comando del objets aunque bueno, creo q lo vi pero no estoy seguro.

Saludos!

Comment: Podrias crear una función que por parametros le pases el id y luego haces la consulta de esta manera -> alumno = Alumnos.objects.get(id="3") y retornas -> alumno.name

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar utilizar:

```
view = Alumnos.objects.filter(id="3").first()
```

o

```
view = Alumnos.objects.get(id="3")
```

Luego podrías acceder a los elementos del alumno encontrado:

```
print(view.name)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! me fue de utilidad! y si quisiera traer no solo un elemento de las clase sino todos los elementos correspondientes a ese ID?

Comment: No se si es para este caso porque supuse que ese id es el del alumno y por ende es único para cada uno de ellos pero si quieres obtener solo los nombres en una lista podrias utilizar el metodo .values('la propiedad') -> Alumnos.objects.all().values('name') :D! no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta :)